# How to say "home improvement" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to help some friends who constantly struggle with home repairs due to lack of home maintenance experience.

I have a [nice English book](https://www.homedepot.com/p/The-Home-Depot-Home-Improvement-3rd-Edition-with-DVD-0696238500/100677237) with a lot of pictures, but it is not very useful for non English speakers.

I tried searching for the Simplified Chinese Google Translate results of "home improvement book", "home repair book", etc only coming across interior design, and appliance repair results.

What is the correct Chinese term for this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something to do it yourself? Try 家居装修DIY

Answer (score 0):

home can be 家庭，improvement/repair can be 装潢/装修，book can be 手册。
So, 家庭装修手册 or 家庭装潢手册

Comment: Your search terms are different than what I used, but I'm still getting home decor results. Plugging into google translate, your first term gives respectively: "Home decoration manual", "Home decor manual".

Comment: Maybe a direct translation won't work.